# R shiny plot layout UI

Tags: r, shiny

Quick question on formatting positions of plots in r Shiny UI.

So far I have made a series of histogram plots in Server.R and they all show perfectly in the UI.  The only problem is, is that I want them to line up in 2 rows, 4 to a row.  My current code, pasted below, gives me 3 rows!  The top one with 4 graphs, the second with 3 graphs (With room to fit a fourth) and then the last row has 1 plot...  Where have I gone wrong and is there a better method to layout 8 plots in shiny?

```
fluidRow(
   column(12,
       "",
       fluidRow(
         column(3,
                plotOutput("PlotHy")#,

         ),
         column(width = 3,
                plotOutput("PlotMe")),
         column(width = 3,
                plotOutput("PlotEthane")),
         column(width = 3,
                plotOutput("PlotEthylene")),
         column(width = 3,
                plotOutput("PlotCO")),
         column(width = 3,
                plotOutput("PlotCO2")),
         column(width = 3,
                plotOutput("PlotO")),
         column(width = 3,
                plotOutput("PlotN"))
       )
)
),
```

Thanks, James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just explicit the row separation:

```
shinyUI(
    fluidPage(

    titlePanel("stack overflow question"),

    fluidRow(
    column(12,
           "",
           fluidRow(
               column(3,
                      plotOutput("PlotHy")),
               column(width = 3,
                      plotOutput("PlotMe")),
               column(width = 3,
                      plotOutput("PlotEthane")),
               column(width = 3,
                      plotOutput("PlotEthylene"))
           ), fluidRow(
               column(width = 3,
                      plotOutput("PlotCO")),
               column(width = 3,
                      plotOutput("PlotCO2")),
               column(width = 3,
                      plotOutput("PlotO")),
               column(width = 3,
                      plotOutput("PlotN"))
           )
    )
)
))
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is, do it in R itself.

Something like this

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    par(mfrow=c(2,2))
    h1 <- hist(rnorm(100))
    h2 <- hist(rnorm(100))
    h3 <- hist(rnorm(100))
    h4 <- hist(rnorm(100))
  })
})
```

Add, plotOutput("plot") wherever you need in the ui.R

Comment: That's a really interesting way to do it